# arrange list items in a specific pattern

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What I am looking to achieve is to arrange items in a list in a specific pattern. Say, I have the following dictionary:

```
>>>dict_a = {
       'north' : 'N',
       'south' : 'S',
       'east' : 'E',
       'west' : 'W',
       'north east' : 'NE',
       'north west' : 'NW'
   }
```

Now to check if a string contains any items from the above dictionary i do :

```
>>>string_a = 'North East Asia'
>>>list_a = []
>>>for item in dict_a:
       if item in string_a.lower():
           list_a.append(item)
```

and it gives me the results as follows, which makes sense

```
>>>['north', 'north east', 'east']
```

but what I want to get is `['north east']` and ignore `north` and `east`. How do i acheive this ?

Comment: check if the first two words of `string_a` build a key in the dict

Comment: Seperate the dict into two, and make a pass with each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [difflib.closest_match](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match)

```
>>> dict_a = {
       'north' : 'N',
       'south' : 'S',
       'east' : 'E',
       'west' : 'W',
       'north east' : 'NE',
       'north west' : 'NW'
   }
>>> import difflib
>>> string_a = 'North East Asia'
>>> dict_a[difflib.get_close_matches(string_a, dict_a.keys())[0]]
'NE'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (new in Python 2.7+) which stores the key/value pairs in a consistent order. To get a single result, simply break the loop after the first match.

```
import collections

# create the mapping with the desired order of matches
dict_a = collections.OrderedDict([
    ('north east', 'NE'),
    ('north west', 'NW'),
    ('north', 'N'),
    ('south', 'S'),
    ('east', 'E'),
    ('west', 'W'),
])

string_a = 'North East Asia'
list_a = []
for item in dict_a:
    if item in string_a.lower():
        list_a.append(item)
        break  # found something
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> max(['north', 'north east', 'east'], key=len)
'north east'
```